# Restrict web service call if https server is hosted with non-secured SSL certificate

Tags: ios, web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate

One https server is hosted with a non-secured SSL certificate, but if I try to do web service call from iOS using `NSURLSession` the same server as it is returning the SUCCESS message(`http status code 200`) with one warning,

```
challenge : <NSURLProtectionSpace: 0x60000000e050>: Host:ucsmv2012.xx.xxxxx.com, Server:https, Auth-Scheme:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust, Realm:(null), Port:7002, Proxy:NO, Proxy-Type:(null)
```

If I try to access the URL in the browser I get the Privacy Error message,

[image: Privacy Error]

Is there a way to restrict the API call if the certificate is not secured?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the following key under NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in your .plist file.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>testdomain.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: it won't help much. As I need to support `http` API calls too

Comment: Then add url without any http or https in NSAppTransportSecurity